# class template errors out

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

ALL,

In my header file I have:

```
template<class T> 
__declspec(dllexport) MyClass : public MyBaseClass // line 1
{
public:
    template <class T>MyClass(T obj);
    ~MyClass();
};
```

In my .cpp file I have:

```
template<class T> __declspec(dllexport) MyClass::MyClass( T obj ) : MyBaseClass() // line 2
{
    // body of the constructor
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}
```

This code errors out on MSVC 2017. MyBaseClass is not a template class.

So I have 2 questions:

1. It shouldn't be necessary to templatize every function in the template class. But removing `template<class T>` from the constructor in both .h and .cpp generate an error.
2. What is the best way to fix an error? Should the base class be a template class as well?

The errors are:

`missing type specifier - int assumed // at line 1` 
`left of :: must be class/struct/union // at line 2`

[EDIT]

To give more background:

I have 2 structs that differs by one extra member that needs to be pushed into this class. So I decided to make it a template class and call the constructor based on the type.

I don't really want to overload constructors since it will be just a code copy-paste, which is not a good design.

[/EDIT]

Comment: btw It is normal to have the bodies of methods of template classes inline in the header file and for there to be no cpp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing some missing keywords in your code and changing the constructor template argument to `R`, because you were already using `T` in the class, you can do the following:

```
//header
template<class T>
class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass : public MyBaseClass {
public:
    template <class R>
    MyClass(R obj);
    ~MyClass();
};

//cpp file
template<class T>
template<class R>
//template<class T, class R> does not work
__declspec(dllexport) MyClass<T>::MyClass<R>(R obj) : MyBaseClass() {}

template<class T>
MyClass<T>::~MyClass() {}
```

If you mean to only have one templated type, you don't need to specify the constructor to be templated:

```
//header
template<class T>
class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass : public MyBaseClass {
public:
    MyClass(T obj);
    ~MyClass();
};

//cpp file
template<class T>
__declspec(dllexport) MyClass<T>::MyClass(T obj) : MyBaseClass() {
    // body of the constructor
}

template<class T>
MyClass<T>::~MyClass() { }
```

Comment: thank you. I was looking for the latter. Now, I'm trying to use this class. It looks like I can't use it as a pointer from the header like `MyClass *o` and then create the actual object in the cpp file like `o = new MyClass<MyType>( bar );` But even if I do it like this: `MyClass *o = new MyClass<MyType>( bar );`, even though I link to the library from where `MyClass` is exported I still get linker error about `undefined external symbol`.

Comment: Compilation succeeded, but linking failed. Any idea?